# Checking for duplicates in two tables with same name columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am an amateur with limited programming language, please help.
I have the following code :

```
try
  {
     $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM m_users WHERE user_email=:umail");
     $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     if($row['user_email']==$umail) {
        $error[] = "Sorry but someone has already registered with this email address !";
     }
     else
     {
        if($user->register($umail,$ucountry,$uip)) 
        {
            $user->redirect('m_c.php');
        }
     }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

This code - as it is - looks for duplicate emails in just one table called `m_users` and throws a notification if it finds one.

What I want is that it looks and checks AS WELL in an **additional** table called `f_users`, which has EXACTLY the same column structure.
I tried different tricks to no avail.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I read, and I am only guessing, you have a table for male users and another for female, you could just merge both tables by dumping one into the other and adding a column for gender. Now there a bunch of ways to approach your problem but I suggest this one, which adds another else statement and runs the same query but changes the table name.

```
<?php 
try{
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_email
        FROM m_users 
        WHERE user_email=:umail");
    $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['user_email']==$umail) {
        $error[] = "Sorry but someone has already registered with this  email address !";
    }else{
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_email
        FROM f_users 
        WHERE user_email=:umail");
        $stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row['user_email']==$umail) {
            $error[] = "Sorry but someone has already registered with this  email address !";
        }
    }else{
        if($user->register($umail,$ucountry,$uip)){
                $user->redirect('m_c.php');
        }
    }
 }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It does somehow work when there's entries in the database and if I select an email which is already in the DB, it throws the notification. When there's no entry in the DB and it has to create one, I get this error: "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens". And you are right, those are males and females, the reason why I build separate tables is that I want to differentiate them on different pages. Your code has an extra } somewhere, I got it out properly. Thanks

Comment: It actually works, sorry, I had an error in my script. Many thanks.

Comment: @Luc it's good this solution has helped you. Could you upvote or accept the answer, this would encourage usage of the Stack Overflow system, and I must admit, it encourages me.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

My PHP is extremely rusty but you could just run another query and check that in the conditional:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM m_users WHERE user_email=:umail");
$stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM f_users WHERE user_email=:umail");
$stmt->execute(array(':umail'=>$umail));
$row_2=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row['user_email']==$umail or $row_2['user_email']=$umail) {
   $error[] = "Sorry but someone has already registered with this email address !";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the SQL query so that it looks for the email address in the two tables in one query?

```
SELECT user_email FROM m_users WHERE user_email=:umail 
UNION 
SELECT user_email FROM f_users WHERE user_email=:umail
```